# Specify Unicode Character in Regular Expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I create a ruby regular expression that includes a unicode character?

For example, I would like to the character "\u0002" in my regular expression.

Comment: Pretty straightforward: `/\u0002/`. Interpolation works inside `//` regexp delimiters.

Comment: Oh man! I assumed the \u would be a literal u. Answer the question so I can accept!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write `/\x02/` :

```
"\u0002" =~ /\x02/
#=> 0
```

If you're not sure, you can just start from a string :

```
Regexp.new("\u0002")
#=> /\x02/
```

Here's another example :

```
"☀☁☂" =~ /\u2602/
#=> 2
```

As mentionned by @TomLord in the comments, you can also specify a range. To check if a string includes a [UTF-8 arrow](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_arrows.asp) :

```
"↹" =~ /[\u2190-\u21FF]/
#=> 0
```

Comment: It is also valid to omit the leading zeros with: `/\u{2}/`

Comment: And if desired, you can specify unicode ranges in the regex exactly how you'd expect: `/[\u{0020}-\u{D7FF}]/`

Comment: Likewise `\u{....}` allows to specify code points above U+FFFF (e.g. `\u{1F600}`) or multiple code points at once, e.g `\u{2600 2601 2602}`