# Ruby regular expression pattern for UTF8 characters with BOM

Tags: regex, ruby

Could you tell me the Ruby regular expression pattern that corresponds to the following Python one.

```
re.compile(b"\x02\xff\xfe(.*?)\x03\xff\xfe")
```

This can be used to identify UTF8 characters with BOM (byte order mark).

Comment: Do you mean using `\u` like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41809166/specify-unicode-character-in-regular-expression

Answer (score 0):

This yields `true`:

```rb
s = "\u0002\u00ff\u00fe123\u0003\u00ff\u00fe"
p /\u0002\u00ff\u00fe(.*?)\u0003\u00ff\u00fe/.match?(s)
```

See [Ruby proof](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v1jBVkEpptTAwMAIRKalgclUQyNjsKAxsqASV4GCPqZaDT0te01M1fp6uYklyRn2GsWa//8DAA).

Use `\uXXXX` notation.